# The SetNull tool does not correctly change "-9999" into NODATA

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, nodata, setnull

I am using ArcMap 10.5.1 and .tif raster data. When I executed the SetNull tool to convert all "-9999" values into NoData, the range of values in the output raster was greater than that in the original raster.

The input raster's value range is (-9999,896.762), but the output value range is (0, 977.176). I don't know how did this operation generate values greater than 896.762.

My arcpy code stand-alone script:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")

inputRas = "C:\\Desktop\\Data\\input.tif"
outputRas = SetNull(inputRas, inputRas, "VALUE = -9999")
outputRas.save("C:\\Desktop\\Results.gdb\\output.tif")
```

I also tried the Con statement and the output values had the same messed-up range as well.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Are you abslutley sure it changed the values? Because ArcMap values are often based on a sample of the data, and now you have no -9999's.

Comment: Do you mean that the value range shown on the Table of Contents may not be accurate?

Comment: You are absolutely right! The reclassification was successful. Thanks!!!